# Help for a mysql query/procedure

Tags: sql, mysql

i've to write a (mysql) sql query/ procedure but i don't know where to start. My goal is to create and show the standings for a sportive tournament. 
My table is like the follow

```
match_id
tournament_id
date
team1
team2
team1_result
team2_result
..
```

So, i've to write via sql something like this "meta language"

```
if team1_result > team2_result 
  team1_point = team1_point + 3
else if team1_result = team2_result 
  team1_point = team1_point + 1
```

Does anyone can help me ? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something more or less like:

```
SELECT team1_result INTO var_team1_result FROM results_table;
SELECT team1_result INTO var_team1_result FROM results_table;

IF var_team1_result > var_team2_result THEN
  UPDATE score_table SET team1_point = team1_point + 3 where [];
ELSE
  UPDATE score_table SET team1_point = team1_point + 1 where [];
END IF;
```

I've made a lot of assumptions there, since you didn't include many details about how your tables are set up.  Hopefully this example is enough to point you in the right direction.  `[]` should be replaced with the needed conditions to update the score in the correct place.